# Looping through SQL table to create a new table based on another table's data

Tags: sql, database, loops, iteration

Is there any way in SQL to loop through a table and create a new table based on the data from another table?

I'm not familiar with T-SQL which has returned in a lot of my searches of this topic but I was wondering if there was a way to do this in plain SQL?

Here's an example of two tables I have: Invoice and EVENT

The table I want to create through iteration is Last Event To Invoice.

Example of Tables:

[image]

I know the logic here but I'm not sure how to achieve this the best way in SQL.

1. Loop through each Invoice and get company ID, invoice date
2. Loop through the EVENT table where company ID = current company ID
3. Get the most recent EVENT prior to invoice_date
4. Put that information into a new table

Answer (score 1):

You're better off writing set-based queries and letting the engine decide than worrying about loops.

Your queries will run row-by-row when needed.

Here's an example with CROSS APPLY, but a subquery or row_number() solution would give the same result.

```
with invoice(invoice_date) as (
select cast('2021-01-10' as date)
) --sample data

, event(event_date) as (
select cast('2021-01-08' as date)
union all select cast('2021-01-11' as date)
union all select cast('2021-01-09' as date)
) --sample data

SELECT Invoice.invoice_date
--other fields here
, e.event_date as last_event_date

FROM Invoice
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 event_date
    FROM event
    WHERE event_date <= invoice_date
    ORDER BY event_date DESC
)e
```

Comment: Would this work for larger data sets? For example when you cast the dates - what if I do not know the dates in advance?

Comment: The dates are just sample data so that this is reproducable, since it wasn't provided in the question. The bit you'll want is at the end.